# Getting a NameError when I run the command rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am following the Michael Hartl's tutorial. I'm still on chapter 1.

It says

```
    undefined local variable or method 'first_app' for main:Object (NameError)
```

which is in my development.rb line 1.

```
    Firstapp::Application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

    # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
    # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
    # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
    config.cache_classes = false

    # Do not eager load code on boot.
    config.eager_load = false

    # Show full error reports and disable caching.
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

    # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
    config.active_support.deprecation = :log

    # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
    config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

    # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
    # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
    # number of complex assets.
    config.assets.debug = true

    # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
    # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
    # Raises helpful error messages.
    config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

    # Raises error for missing translations
    # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
    end
```

I followed other questions on StackOverflow with no solution. Some of them require to changed my app name from

```
    Rails.application.configure do
```

to

```
    First_app::Application.configure do
```

which didn't resolve anything. Oh and if it helps, I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

When you ran the `rails new` command it should have properly set your app's name. I think what happened is you probably ran `rails new firstapp` instead of `rails new first_app`. Change`First_app::Application.configure do` to `FirstApp::Application.configure do`. You should also probably do a search in your project for Firstapp or First_App and change those as well.

Answer (score 1):

It had something to do with my Gem file apparently. I didn't edit it this and left it alone, the application ended up compiling without any errors. I think it has something to do with SQLite3 gem that I'm not properly doing something regarding version.